# Change tableView style from UITableViewStylePlain to UITableViewStyleGrouped in subclass method

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I have a `ViewControllerA` contains a tableView with `UITableViewStylePlain` style, like this:

```
- (void)loadView{
    [super loadView];

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}
```

Now, I have a `ViewControllerSubA`, subClass of `ViewControllerA`, most logic is same with `ViewControllerA`, but the tableView's style should be `UITableViewStyleGrouped`. What's I have to do is to create a new tableView with `UITableViewStyleGrouped` style, with this code:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    [self.tableView removeFromSuperview];
    self.tableView = nil;

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}
```

Are there any better solutions? I don't think to remove old table view and then crate a new one seem good.

Comment: Is it ARC based project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use polymorphism!

Change your code in Base class to

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
//..... additional code here
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:[self getTableStyle]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}

- (UITableViewStyle)getTableStyle
{
    return UITableViewStylePlain;
}
```

And in your Child class you should add

```
- (UITableViewStyle)getTableStyle
{
    return UITableViewStyleGrouped;
}
```

It is called "Factory Method".